# $1+a$ and $1-a$ in a ring are invertible if $a$ is nilpotent

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, nilpotence

Let $(A, +, \cdot)$ be a ring with $1$.  An element $a\in A$ is *nilpotent* if there exists $n\in \mathbb{N}$ so that $a^n=0$.

> Show that if $a$ is nilpotent then $1+a$ and $1-a$ are invertible.

Comment: Hint:What is $1-a^n$?

Comment: Why voted to close?

Comment: @Sigur Seriously?

Answer (score 4):

$1 = 1 - {a^n} = (1 - a)(1 + a + \cdots + {a^{n - 1}})$

If $n$ is an odd number it's the same for $1+a$: $1 = 1 + {a^n} = (1 + a)\sum\limits_{k = 0}^{n - 1} {{{( - 1)}^k}{a^k}} $.

Comment: Perhaps you could note that you choose $n$ large enough so that $a^n=0$, and _take_ $n$ odd so that you can apply the second formula.

Comment: It's not necessary to treat $1+a$ separately: just replace $a$ by $-a$. (Why can we do it?)