# If $A$ has no non-trivial idempotents, then neither does $A/N$

Tags: commutative-algebra, nilpotence, idempotents, quotient-set

Let $A$ be a commutative, associative, unital, finitely generated algebra over an algebraically closed field $k$. Denote by $N$ the nilradical of $A$, which is the set of all nilpotent elements of $A$ (or equivalently the intersection of all prime ideals of $A$).

Suppose that $A$ has no non-trivial idempotents. Is it true that $A/N$ also contains no non-trivial idempotents?

Aiming for a contradiction, let $e\in A/N$ be a non-trivial idempotent, then $e^2=e$ in $A/N$. In other words, $e^2-e\in N$. Then we know that there is some $n\ge 1$ such that $e^n(1-e)^n=0$. But then $\forall m\ge 1: \left((e(1-e))^m\right)^n=0$, hence $(e(1-e))^m\in N$. Does this necessarily imply that $e(1-e)=0$ in $N$, hence in $A$, contradicting that $A$ has no non-trivial idempotents?

Thank you.

Comment: This might be helpful: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00J9

Answer (score 1):

Yes, because [idempotents lift modulo a nil ideal](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2024262/29335) (or also [this](http://www.math.hawaii.edu/%7Elee/algebra/idempotent.pdf).)  If there were a nontrivial idempotent of $A/N$, then it would lift to a nontrivial idempotent of $A$. (This is not hard to show.)